# How to run wp cli from a wp hook?

Tags: wp-cli, code, wp-api

How can I run a wp cli command when a wordpress hook is called on my website.

On user registration hook, I would like to run a wp cli command to activate a license.

Comment: WP ClI has it's name suggests is a command line utility.
It's not made to be run from php.
Consider editing your question further, add some more information on what you are trying, does it involve a database operation, a file operation, a post request?

Comment: @Toffee "It's not made to be run from php" - the WP CLI *is* php so I guess you mean it's not made to be run through an HTTP request. But that's not the point - he is of course only asking how to **trigger** the CLI command through a browser request - which is completely valid if you have some long-running process that is not fit to run as part of an HTTP request.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you want to do. If you want to run the PHP code that's behind the WP-CLI code you might consider looking at https://github.com/wp-cli/entity-command

Maybe you don't actually need WP-CLI but the corresponding code behind it. Most WP-CLI commands have Wordpress equivalents. For example of what I was trying to do today, the `wp menu create "My Menu"` command is defined here:
https://github.com/wp-cli/entity-command/blob/master/src/Menu_Command.php. (It was much easier to find documentation for WP-CLI for this because 99% of results for Wordpress describe how to do it via the admin panel.)

Basically it just uses the WP function:

```
65:     $menu_id = wp_create_nav_menu( $args[0] );
```

So  `> wp menu create "My Menu"` on the commandline is roughly equivalent to `wp_create_nav_menu('My Menu')` in a `functions.php` file.

Similarly, the plugin command would be addressed as a WP-CLI extension command defined in [Plugin_Command.php](https://github.com/wp-cli/extension-command/blob/master/src/Plugin_Command.php) which uses the Wordpress command [activate_plugin()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/activate_plugin/). If you want to know the WP version of the WP-CLI command you could look it up yourself or include the specific command you want to know in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PHP exec() function to run wp-cli commands.

Example: `<?php exec('wp core download'); ?>`

Use with care. Further reading:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php